# Special character in WCF url $ no longer on WIndows 2012 with .NET 4.5

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012, uritemplate

I have a WCF REST API which uses uri templates.  One of these Uri templates looks like this:
[WebGet(UriTemplate="List/Data.svc/$count")].

In windows 2008r2 this url works fine, but fails on some 2012 servers. When I look at the logs (logs I internally write, not the IIS logs), the 2008r2 request looks like this:

```
"http://myserver:40217/List/Data.svc/$count"
```

The 2012 server url looks like this:

```
"http://myserver:40217/List/Data.svc/%24count"
```

The exact same app on the same device is making both requests, so I am 99.999% sure this is not a difference in how the app is making the request.

Does WCF do any url encoding for incoming requests?

There are quite a few KB fixes related to .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012 for WCF, but I cannot find a comprehensive list, and I have not found one that seems to be related to this issue.

On a Windows 2012 server, if you go to .../test.svc/$test  it works and you will see "test succesful!".  If you do the same on a Windows Server 2012 r2 server, you will get "Bad!! This is not the right route!"

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "$test")]
    public System.IO.Stream GetTest() 
    { 
        return new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test succesful!")); 
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
    public System.IO.Stream GetById(string id) 
    {
        if (id == "$test")
            return new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "Bad!! This is not the right route!"));
        else
            return
                new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("You did a get by Id on " + id));

    }
```

Comment: I'm from .net framework compatibility team. I can reproduce this issue. I noticed that WCF still matches the UriTemplate fine even though the URI has an escaped '$' instead of '$' and invokes the correct [WebGet] operation. I notice the issue happens only when I try to access the RequestUri from the UriTemplate property from WebOperationContext. May I ask you what kind of an issue you are running into due to this (or other side effects because of this).

Comment: On my own test 2012 server I do not seem to have problems. I have a client server I am troubleshooting where it does not find the template match.  So the discrepancy in how $ is escaped may be a red herring on my issue.  It is hard to tell because I have not been able to pin it down.  I am using WCF tracing to troubleshoot but the WCF tracing does not provide enough information on the template matching heuristic to help me determine why it matches on one server but not the other.

Comment: Turns out, the client was on 2012 r2!  So I suspect the bug is specific to that OS.  I will be getting an environment set up to verify.

Comment: I tried running the same repro on a WS 2012 R2 machine. I still see the UriTemplate matches and has an unescaped '$' in the Uri though. May be I am missing something. Could you send a simple repro project to netfx45compat at microsoft.com?

Comment: To my original post I added a very simple sample project that shows the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to this issue.  They are described in this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2014/01/24/case-study-wcf-web-http-routes-dollar-differently-in-iis-8-5.aspx

I tested both of these fixes and they work well for 2012r2.